# Segue not working correctly. No back button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `UILabel` connected to a `Tap Gesture Recognizer`

[image]

The `Tap Gesture Recognizer` is connected to my 'Sign Up' page

[image]

When I tap the label, the 'Sign Up' screen shows, but like this with no back button even though it is depicted as having a back button in my storyboard. My initial screen is also embedded in a `Navigation Controller`, so that is not the problem. What gives? Why is the new screen showing up like this with and with no back button?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you presenting the previous view controller?  My guess is that you are presenting it directly, rather than presenting its navigation controller

Comment: @Paulw11 You are correct. I am using view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() but I can't show the screen via a button since it shows automatically after asynchronous code

Comment: That is OK, but you need to make sure the root view controller is the navigation controller, not whatever the green view controller is.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the navigation controller to the initial view controller, but it still doesn't work as expected. I've edited the question to have my storyboard included

Comment: There is no segue between the first green VC and the login VC - How do you get from the first green vc to the second green vc (login)?

Comment: @Paulw11 After asynchonous code is done, I call
let signupViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.signupViewController) as? SignUp
        
        view.window?.rootViewController = signupViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209731/discussion-between-paulw11-and-garren-fitzenreiter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are replacing the current root view controller with your new sign up view controller instance, the navigation controller is being discarded.

You should use a segue to present the sign up view controller.  You can trigger a segue in code using `performSegue(identifier: sender:)`